# how to fetch mysql records after every 30 min

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to fetch records from `MySQL DB`, after every 30 minutes based on id of particular date stamp.

I tried following but failed to get:

```
SELECT * FROM alert_alert
WHERE timestamp
DATE_FORMAT('2021-07-21 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL 30 MINUTE, '%Y-%m-01 %H:%i');
```

Comment: The title of your question is a little ambiguous. It seems you want to get all records within a certain time-range, correct? The title reads as if you want to run a query every 30 minutes. Maybe change it to "SQL select all records within 30 minutes of a timestamp"?

Comment: try mysql events

Comment: sorry for my title ... i want to fetch records from a table called alert where  i have a foreign key called asset ... based on asset i have to fetch one record for every half and  hour on yesterday date